# first time trying to learn "mount"

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk

is it just best practices to mount in media, or is it ok or irrelevant if i wanted to mount in my home or user file instead of a root file like media?

Also, the "unmount" isnt all that clear to me. So it is necessary to run "umount" when I need to remove the pendrive, like windows "eject"? will it automatically mount itself when i reinsert? Im working in a VMWare Ubuntu, and things are not working out very straight forward. I gave up and used GUI, but that is not going well at the moment either, i.e., no option to mount. I have formatted twice hoping for different results.
EDIT: I am running the most recent version of ubuntu 23.04 Lunar. I have no specific needs, apps, etc;i am a noob  simply a general understanding of the how and what. "The Linux Command Line" by William Shuuts is outdated for this chapter and there a few commands that my system wont perform. there seems to be at least 5 different commands I have come across to find the name and location of the pendrive, some dont work. Id be happy to read whatever you tell me to.

Comment: It's up to you where you `mount` partitions, however there can be consequences if you `mount` in specific locations, which is why `/mnt/` and `/media/` are usually used (ie. *consequences can be less there*).  You gave no specifics as to Ubuntu product, release of that product, nor apps you're using, as these all play into the decision(s).  FYI:  I have network mounts on this machine which are mounted twice; once in `/mnt/` so I can use it *trouble-free* (in some apps; eg. *snap* packages which run *confined*) and in another location that I sure prefer in other cases.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus *unsupported* on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your statement "*the most recent version of ubuntu 23.04 Lunar*" is **incorrect**, Ubuntu 23.04 has been able to *release-upgrade* to Ubuntu 23.10 or the 2023-October release for more than 3 months (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades) with Ubuntu 23.10 the *latest* release of Ubuntu.  Your release is EOL with warnings notices of the EOL going out last month (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/12/15/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reaches-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) which your system would have also told you (*unless you disabled that*)

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you where you mount partitions, however there can be consequences if you mount in specific locations, which is why `/mnt/` and `/media/` are usually used (ie. consequences can be minimized by using those locations).

You gave no specifics as to Ubuntu product, release of that product, nor apps you're using, as these all play into the decision(s).

FYI: I have network mounts on this machine which are mounted twice; once in `/mnt/` so I can use it trouble-free (in some apps; eg. *snap* packages which run *confined*) and in another location that I sure prefer in most apps. Most of my mounts are automatic, via my placement of them in the *file-system table* (ie. `/etc/fstab`); though some listed there are also `noauto` being mounted only when required (backup scripts etc).

Comment: The OP providing specifics as requested would contribute to making the question less opinion-based.